# Codepoint 984652 not found in font Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Building with sound null safety

Codepoint 984652 not found in font, aborting.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           46.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: i'm having the same issue

Comment: i think it happened when i added firebase, does your project have that?

Comment: Yes i use firebase

Comment: i guess that is the issue, it happened to me when i added it, the give solution works for me though

Answer (score 2):

try building your application with this `flutter build apk --no-tree-shake-icons`

Comment: it's not a good approach to go with this command, as it adds additional 2-3 MBs to the build

Comment: Yes, this is just a workaround to the issue, this is no longer happening in later versions

Answer (score 0):

- There is an issue with icons in Flutter 2.10.0 which causes this error. I am assuming that you are using 2.10.0 version of Flutter.
- This issue is resolved in Flutter 2.10.2. So, run **Flutter upgrade** in the terminal to solve the problem.